# Angle range of Gy-25 sensor

Tags: arduino, gyroscope

I am measuring the angle of a link with the Gy-25 sensor using Arduino mega2560 with the UART protocol. I need to have the pitch angle and according to its datasheet, the angle range is from -20 to 85 and then starts to decrease again. Is there any way to have this angle in 360?
I don't know if it's possible to convert this Euler angle to a quaternion? and how?
The sensor and its datasheet:
https://bsfrance.fr/modules-rc-drones/606-GY25-capteur-de-position-angulaire-MPU6050-MCU-tilt-angle-module-UART-GY-25.html

```
float Roll,Pitch,Yaw;
unsigned char Re_buf[8],counter=0;
void setup()
{
Serial.begin(115200);
Serial3.begin(115200);// SoftwareSerial can only support 9600 baud rate for GY 25 but Serial3 can support 115200 and 9600 both
delay(4000);     
Serial3.write(0XA5);
Serial3.write(0X54);//correction mode
delay(4000);
Serial3.write(0XA5);
Serial3.write(0X51);//0X51:query mode, return directly to the angle value, to be sent each read, 0X52:Automatic mode,send a direct return angle, only initialization

}

void loop() {
serialEvent();
Serial.print("roll= ");
Serial.print(Roll);
Serial.print(" pitch= ");                 
Serial.print(Pitch);
Serial.print(" yaw= ");                 
Serial.print(Yaw);
}

void serialEvent() {
Serial3.write(0XA5);
Serial3.write(0X51);//send it for each read
while (Serial3.available()) {   
Re_buf[counter]=(unsigned char)Serial3.read();
if(counter==0&&Re_buf[0]!=0xAA) return;       
counter++;       
if(counter==8)               
{   
  counter=0;                 
  if(Re_buf[0]==0xAA && Re_buf[7]==0x55)  // data package is correct     
    {         
     Yaw=(int16_t)(Re_buf[1]<<8|Re_buf[2])/100.00;   
     Pitch=(int16_t)(Re_buf[3]<<8|Re_buf[4])/100.00;
     Roll=(int16_t)(Re_buf[5]<<8|Re_buf[6])/100.00;
    }     
} 
}
}
```

Comment: where did you find this information?  "the angle range is from -20 to 85 and then starts to decrease again."  it is not in the datasheet linked on the product page you provided in your post. so what are you talking about?

Comment: @Piglet you're right and it wasn't in that datasheet but by the Arduino code that I attached, I tested the sensor and found this range. On another website, I found another datasheet that is in Chinese, and it's been written the same range for the pitch angle that I got. <https://hacktronics.co.in/accelero-baro-magnetometer/gy-25-mpu-6050-serial-port-data-output-inclination-module>

Comment: how did you test and find this range? I don't see anything about -20 to 85 in the code provided, as you claim

Comment: @Piglet, I just attached the sensor on a link and rotated the link around the one side of the link in order to find the link angle. By the wiring, which is shown in the first web site that I attached and the Arduino code, I got this range. There is no conversion in the code, the value that the sensor returns is between -20 to 85 degrees, and I saw this in the Arduino serial monitor.

Comment: I was just curious if you actually got those values or if it was just a guess because -20 to 85° is the ambient temperature range. another datasheet mentions -40 to 85.

Comment: @Piglet, I removed the sensor from the link and attached it on a breadboard. The range of pitch angle that I got was different. Sometimes it's near -90 to 90, but next time that I compile the code, the range was less than before like I said!!
My question is if there is a way that I convert this angular range into 0 to 360 because, as I said, It goes up and then starts to decrease. I don't if It's possible and could be useful to use quaternion angles and how to implement that?